# While navigating to another screen, the navigation bar color shows white for a while the original color is red

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I'm working on **MainController** as it contains tableView with some sample cells. I'm customizing the **nagivation bar** just like the **gif file** below.

[image]

Here is code of this file to customize the navigation bar. I call it in **viewWillAppear**.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil

navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

When I click one cell, it will navigate to the **DetailsController**. And here is the code that I customize the navigation bar. I call it in **viewDidLoad**.

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
let statusBarColor = UIColor.red
statusBarView.backgroundColor = statusBarColor
view.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

My problem is when I click on the cell, I notice that the navigation bar changes color to white first before starting navigating to another screen. It does not look nice. Do you know how to fix it?

Thanks.